# Noise in Ray-Tracing with GLSL compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, raytracing, compute-shader

I'm making a GLSL Ray-tracer with LWJGL, following [*Ray Tracing in One Weekend*](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html). And when I render with 100000 samples per pixel, I get the following image: [some spheres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juk00.png)

Whenever I render with about 2-3000 samples or more, some line-look-alike noise appears, as seen in the picture and it gets more and more pronounced with more samples. I suspect that the reason for this may be my `random()` function for generating rays may not be fully uniform. I use this:

```
float random(vec2 co){
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}
```

and I use it that way: `random(pixel_coords + random_seed)`, where `ivec2 pixel_coords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);`, and `random_seed` is a float uniform, set with `rand.nextFloat()` for every call of the shader (so it is unique for every sample, but the same for all pixels in one sample image).

Can this not be a problem with the random number generation, but something else? Are there any more-perfect ways to generate randomness?

Comment: Thank you, @httpdigest. I found out that if I replace pixel_coords with pixel_coords / resolution.xy, aka map the random seed closer to the range (0, 1), the function behaves much better and the noise disappears. Still I will consider swapping that fuction for a better one.

Comment: @BorisVassilev: maybe look at how [some shadertoys](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4lfGWr) do that.